# fetch data from sql and display it in grids

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a blogging website (just to learn web development) where users enter their details like name, contact, email, picture, blog etc.
The data is being successfully inserted into and fetched from the data base using php and mysqli.

What I want to achieve is to display the data in the form of grids same way as videos are displayed on youtube and we can click to open a video. but I don't have the faintest idea on where to begin I have done research on the web but the tutorials only show how to display data in a single table.

Comment: _"I have done research"_ - Not enough. You should go through a bunch of HTML- and CSS-tutorials and actually make some attempts. There are _many_ ways of doing this. However, the question is too broad in it's current state since it doesn't contain any attempt or a _specific_ issue.